# How to re-execute a TFS CI build set for a pull request

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have set a CI build for every Pull request. If a build fails for some reason, is there a way to re-initiate the build for the same PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply re-run the  failed build in pull request page under **Policies**,  click queue build, such as below:

[image] [image]

Just pay attention, **do not directly re-run build with the same pipeline** other than queue the build policy from PR page, it's a little difference here.

> Queuing the build policy from PR page does a little more than just
>   rerunning a build. It first needs to check if the target branch has
>   moved and create a new merge commit if needed. In that case it will
>   queue a completely new build and not rerunning the existing one. In
>   addition, PR source branch could move and rerunning of the build on
>   old merge commit would have no effect on PR policy. So at this point
>   we do not see much value in investing in this scenario.
>
> Source: [Rerunning failed build doesn't always count towards PR
>   requirement](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/639508/rerunning-failed-build-doesnt-always-count-towards.html)